# Using a journalist recorder for field recordings

Tags: recording, field-recording, portable-recorder

I was plotting to buy one of these digital audio recorders for journalists, which I want to use for field recordings.

Are these devices good for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question right you want to record nature sounds?

For this use i would recommend the Zoom H2n.
It is a very sensitiv mobile recorder. 
Have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, I want to record that kind of sounds. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The question I would ask is for what application?
What is it you want to record??
- I have used quite a few of these (from the older style where you had a small micro-cassette to the more modern digital style) and if you are recording voice only they can be helpful. I used these as a paperless way to take notes, record information after exiting sales meetings etc and reviewed these at the end of the day as a way to keep track of details etc.
One consideration is that the built in microphones do not have a wide field so you really have to be near the subject / person to get really clear recordings, although I have used them to some success recording lectures, but only if the subject was using a mic/pa.
Hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: Or you could just use the voice recorder on your smartphone...as I do now.